# Cannot access shared folder in XP PC within a VPN Network

Tags: windows-xp, firewall

I cannot access shared folder in an XP PC. Here is the scenario.

### PC-1:

OS: Windows-XP
IP: 192.168.8.210/24
Firewall On
File & Printer Sharing is Allowed 
Port 139, 445, 137, 138 is allowed | Scope: Subnet

PC-2: 192.168.7.175/24
OS: Windows 7

Related Information.
1 It is a VPN using two Microtik Router.
2 I can ping the pcs vice versa
3 I can remote desktop 192.168.8.210
4 But when i try to access a folder shared from my 192.168.7.175 | it says that windows cannot access //192.168.8.210
5 I have also tried with hostname.
6 also tried with //192.168.8.210/sharename/   but didn't work.
7 When I turned off the firewall in 192.168.8.210 | I can access the shared folder.

So I need yours help to resolve the issue.

Thanks.
- Shahidul

Answer (score 0):

You will need to allow the remote PC's subnet in the firewall rules, too.

The rule you have added on the host PC for subnet 192.168.8.0/24 allows other PCs *in that subnet* to access the PC's resources. All other PCs, i.e. PCs from other subnets, will be blocked. So add the subnet 192.168.7.0/24 to the host PC's firewall rules and you should be fine.

Note 1: If you just want that one PC to access the share, you can, of course, allow that single IP address (192.168.7.175) in, and not the whole subnet (192.168.7.0/24).

Note 2: If you're only concerned to have that remote PC access the share and you don't need to have other PCs on the host's subnet access the share, you can remove the rule for 192.168.8.0/24 from the firewall. Then all PCs will be left out *except* the one on the remote VPN network.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I have already tried both including the IP: 192.168.7.175 and 192.168.7.0/24 sub-net. Still not working.

Comment: Have you distinguished between UDP and TCP? You should have *TCP* 139 and 445 open, and *UDP* 137 and 138. (See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731402.aspx and https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff633412(v=WS.10).aspx)

Comment: Bump... Any update on this, Muhammad?

Comment: Thanks for help. the problem solved by adding the local ip in the source pc's firewall rule.